# Filtering latest 3 days birthday records from MS Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to filter the employees records whose birthday falls during  last 3 days including today on the basis of `birthday_date` column in the `tb_Employee` table in MS Access .
I know I can get latest 3 days record on the basis of date:

```
Select * from tb_Employee where ([Date_Column] >= NOW()-3
```

But in my case in `birthday_date` column date is in past year (say 18/1/1975). Please help me to fix this

Example:
[image]

Comment: How is `18/1/1975` "in [the] past year"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think they mean "in [a] past year"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might suggest:

```
select * from tb_employee 
where 
    (dateserial(year(date()),month(birthday_date),day(birthday_date)) between date()-3 and date()) or
    (dateserial(year(date())-1,month(birthday_date),day(birthday_date)) between date()-3 and date())
```

In words, this query is stating:

*"Select employees for which their Birthday this year is between the last 3 days and today, or their Birthday last year is between the last 3 days and today"*

Answer (score 2):

If you want peoples whose birthdays are in the past three days, here is one method:

```
where dateserial(year(date()), month(dob), day(dob)) in
        (
         date(), dateadd("d", -1, date()), dateadd("d", -2, "date"),
         dateadd("y", 1, dateadd("d", -1, date())), 
         dateadd("y", 1, dateadd("d", -2, "date"))
        )
```

The last two handle Dec 30th and Dec 31st.